Copy and overwrite from sub folder to another subfolder in the parent folder
I'm trying to make dll for a LetahlCompany mod. The objective is to copy/paste audio files from my mod to another one so people can just click "update" when I add more audio.
I can't just set the directory (c:/user/mod/files) since the files are using profiles (c:/user/profiles/mod/files).
So i want to copy the files like that:

:Profile\Parent\MyModSub\FILES


to


:Profile\Parent\OtherModSub\FILES

So in this case it can be "Profile1" or "Profile2" so its not as simple as copy past of the file directory
I'm a total noob in coding, i'm trying to understand what i'm doing but its hard. And there is multiple ways to do one thing so I don't know what I'm looking for exaclty while doing my research.
So here is the code that will I think work the way I want.
namespace SoundsMove
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string ModSource = @"C:\Users\SpLinTeR\AppData\Roaming\r2modmanPlus-local\LethalCompany\profiles\Hide'N'Seek\BepInEx\plugins\MyMod\MySounds\";
            string ModDest = @"C:\Users\SpLinTeR\AppData\Roaming\r2modmanPlus-local\LethalCompany\profiles\Hide'N'Seek\BepInEx\plugins\TheMod\HisSounds\";

            var allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(ModSource);
            foreach (var file in allFiles)
            {
                var FileModDest = ModDest + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) + Path.GetExtension(file);
                File.Move(file, FileModDest);
            }
        }
    }
}

But as I said, the profile can be named anything, for me its "Hide'N'Seek".
You can see that I have to go back 2 parents folders, then get to 2 subs solfers.
This is a code I found on youtube, I didn't find a way to get back 2 parents back then move it 2 sub again. I don't even know how to code to avoid writing the whole path to my files.

Try: How do I get and set Environment variables in C#? and check: What is "%AppData%"?

Bear in mind that File.Move() will move the files; ie: delete the originals. Maybe File.copy()? This question is a bit broad and vague. As for the two folders, how is your app to be driven? By user input? By command line? a UI? Or some fairly static configuration? Kept where?

If your concern is mainly with the user profiles...you could loop through all folders in the "profiles" folder and make copies for all.  Or, if you need to operate on exactly one folder in the "profiles" folder, you can ship your application with a config file that allows the end user to set the profile folder value.  Then your application reads the config, which has a known name and location, and gets the correct profile value from the config.

It will be a dll load by the launcher. We need to see this like I don't have the path. I know that the folders are in the same parent.
Sorry, its hard for me to explain cause english isn't my first language and I don't know how to code at all, I can't use specific terms for you to understand what I mean.

???\BepInEx\plugins\MyFolder\Mod.dll file-1 file-2 file-3 --- ???\BepInEx\plugins\DestinationFolder\Sounds*where I need my files to go*

???\BepInEx\plugins\MyFolder\Mod.dll --- ???\BepInEx\plugins\DestinationFolder\Sounds\file-1 file-2 file-3

using System;
using System.IO;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string sourceFolder = @"C:\Users\SpLinTeR\AppData\Roaming\r2modmanPlus-local\LethalCompany\profiles\Hide'N'Seek\BepInEx\plugins\MyMod\MySounds\";
        string destinationFolder =@"C:\Users\SpLinTeR\AppData\Roaming\r2modmanPlus-local\LethalCompany\profiles\Hide'N'Seek\BepInEx\plugins\TheMod\HisSounds\";

        SyncFolders(sourceFolder, destinationFolder);
    }

static void SyncFolders(string sourceFolder, string destinationFolder)
{
    // Create the destination folder if it doesn't exist
    if (!Directory.Exists(destinationFolder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationFolder);
    }

    // Get all files in the source folder
    var sourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);

    foreach (var sourceFile in sourceFiles)
    {
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(sourceFile);
        string destFile = Path.Combine(destinationFolder, fileName);

        // Copy the file if it doesn't exist or if it is newer than the destination file
        if (!File.Exists(destFile) || File.GetLastWriteTime(sourceFile) > File.GetLastWriteTime(destFile))
        {
            File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);
            Console.WriteLine($"Copied: {fileName}");
        }
    }
}

}

My main issue is more with moving them from the path. If I give you my code, you'll have to change it so the source and the destination fit your path. That is my issue, i'm supposed to give that to other people.  I can change it to "%AppData%" so it won't need to go to windows users first but after, r2modman use unique profiles from players where they choose the name of that profile. But either way thanks for the help.

static void Main(string[] args)
{
if (args.Length == 0)
{
Console.WriteLine("Please provide a folder path as a command-line argument.");
return;
}
    string folderPath = args[0];
    Console.WriteLine($"Parsed folder path: {folderPath}");
}  and run it from cmd like dotnet run "C:\path\to\your\folder".  Then the user can specify where to put the files (destionation folder) and your folder would be hardcoded


Find a way
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using BepInEx;

[BepInPlugin("com.SpLinTeR.Taunt_FR", "Taunt_FR", "1.0.3")]
public class FolderMoverMod : BaseUnityPlugin
{
    private void Awake()
    {
        CopyFolder();
    }

    public void CopyFolder()
    {
        // Obtenir le répertoire de la DLL (où le mod est situé)
        string dllDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);

        // Remonter au dossier parent de la DLL, soit "plugins"
        string pluginsDirectory = Directory.GetParent(dllDirectory)?.FullName;

        if (pluginsDirectory == null)
        {
            Logger.LogError("Impossible de trouver le dossier plugins.");
            return;
        }

        // Chemins des dossiers SpLinTeRTV-Hide_And_Seek_SoundsFR/Sounds et Gogozooom-Hide_And_Seek/Sounds dans le répertoire "plugins"
        string soundsDirectory = Path.Combine(pluginsDirectory, "SpLinTeRTV-Hide_And_Seek_SoundsFR", "Sounds");
        string targetDirectory = Path.Combine(pluginsDirectory, "Gogozooom-Hide_And_Seek", "Sounds");

        // Vérifier que le dossier "Sounds" existe dans SpLinTeRTV-Hide_And_Seek_SoundsFR
        if (!Directory.Exists(soundsDirectory))
        {
            Logger.LogError($"Le dossier Sounds n'existe pas dans SpLinTeRTV-Hide_And_Seek_SoundsFR : {soundsDirectory}");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            // Si le dossier cible "Sounds" dans Gogozooom-Hide_And_Seek existe, on le supprime avec son contenu
            if (Directory.Exists(targetDirectory))
            {
                Directory.Delete(targetDirectory, true); // true pour supprimer le contenu aussi
                Logger.LogInfo($"Le dossier Sounds a été supprimé dans Gogozooom-Hide_And_Seek : {targetDirectory}");
            }

            // Copier le dossier "Sounds" vers Gogozooom-Hide_And_Seek
            CopyDirectory(soundsDirectory, targetDirectory);
            Logger.LogInfo($"Le dossier {soundsDirectory} a été copié vers {targetDirectory}.");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logger.LogError($"Erreur lors de la copie du dossier : {ex.Message}");
        }
    }

    // Méthode pour copier un dossier et son contenu récursivement
    public static void CopyDirectory(string sourceDir, string destDir)
    {
        // Créer le répertoire de destination s'il n'existe pas
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destDir);

        // Copier les fichiers dans le répertoire de destination
        foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir))
        {
            string destFile = Path.Combine(destDir, Path.GetFileName(file));
            File.Copy(file, destFile, true); // true pour écraser les fichiers existants
        }

        // Copier les sous-dossiers récursivement
        foreach (string subDir in Directory.GetDirectories(sourceDir))
        {
            string destSubDir = Path.Combine(destDir, Path.GetFileName(subDir));
            CopyDirectory(subDir, destSubDir); // Appel récursif pour copier les sous-dossiers
        }
    }
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
